# Resolving a bug in identifying sequences in 3-match game

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, depth-first-search

I'm working on a school project, and developing a 3-match game (based on Match Masters).

I'm stuck in a while trying to solve a bug regarding the mechanism which identifies the sequences, and structures them into a form which can be processed.

The identification of the sequences is done with DFS, and then a different method is used to count the size of each sequence (now it returns it as a list of lists, each list is a sequence of gems, that due to that is needed to be this way for other implementations, such as identifying whether there are any possible matches on the board).

Currently, there's a bug: some sequences can't be identified. It usually happens at the margins.

Here are the relevant method's code:

```java
    public Quartet<HashMap<Gem, Gem>, HashMap<Gem, Integer>, HashMap<Gem, Integer>, AtomicInteger> DFS() {
        HashMap<Gem, Color> color = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Gem, Gem> pi = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Gem, Integer> d = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Gem, Integer> f = new HashMap<>();
        AtomicInteger time = new AtomicInteger();

        Consumer<Gem> DFS_visit = new Consumer<Gem>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Gem u) {
                color.put(u, Color.GRAY);
                time.getAndIncrement();
                d.put(u, time.intValue());

                for (Gem vertex : u.adj()) {
                    if (color.get(vertex) == Color.WHITE) {
                        pi.put(vertex, u);
                        this.accept(vertex);
                    }
                }
                color.put(u, Color.BLACK);
                f.put(u, time.incrementAndGet());
            }
        };

        for (Gem u : Gem.getAllGems()) {
            color.put(u, Color.WHITE);
            pi.put(u, null);
        }

        for (Gem u : Gem.getAllGems()) {
            if (color.get(u) == Color.WHITE) {
                DFS_visit.accept(u);
            }
        }

        return new Quartet<>(pi, d, f, time);
    }

    private LinkedList<LinkedList<Gem>> sequenceGems(HashMap<Gem, Gem> pi, IntPredicate f) {
        LinkedList<LinkedList<Gem>> gems = new LinkedList<>();
        HashMap<Gem, Integer> lengths = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Gem, LinkedList<Gem>> duplicatesHelper = new HashMap<>();

        LinkedList<Gem> gemsToUpdate = new LinkedList<>();
        int length = 0;
        Gem gem = null, ancestor = null;

        for (Gem i : pi.keySet()) {
            gem = i;
            length = 0;

            do {
                gemsToUpdate.push(gem);
                if (pi.get(gem) == null) ancestor = gem;
                gem = pi.get(gem);
                length++;
            } while (gem != null);

            if (!(duplicatesHelper.containsKey(ancestor)) || (length > duplicatesHelper.get(ancestor).size())) { // (!(lengths.containsKey(ancestor)) || (length > lengths.get(ancestor)))
                for (Gem g : gemsToUpdate) {
                    if (duplicatesHelper.containsKey(g)) {
                        int loc = gems.indexOf(duplicatesHelper.get(g));
                        if (loc != -1) gems.remove(loc);
                    }

                    lengths.put(g, length);
                }
            }

            LinkedList<Gem> tmp = (LinkedList<Gem>) gemsToUpdate.clone();
            for (Gem g : gemsToUpdate) {
                duplicatesHelper.put(g, tmp);
            }

            gems.push(tmp);

            gemsToUpdate.clear();
        }

        return gems.stream().filter(i -> f.test(i.size())).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I couldn't find where the bug occurs.

Comment: You need to explain what is a 3-match game, what is the input and what is the expected output. And for what input your code doesn't work.

Comment: I refereed to the game i based my project on, As for the other questions: The 2nd method receives the pi vector that returns from the DFS function and the lambda function which determines what sequences are valid (by length) - by default: length of the sequence >= 3. The 1st Method is just a DFS implementation